# Is there any point in re-specifying an interface that is already inherited?

Tags: .net, oop, interface

I'm a fan of C# but I guess this is an OOP question in general:

In the code shown below, is there any point in re-specifying that `class B` implements `interface I`?

```
interface I { }
class A : I { }
class B : A, I { }
```

As far as I can tell the answer is no, except perhaps for readability if a class implements many interfaces and you would like to emphasize a particular one when declaring the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't. In fact, it can become a little confusing when you keep re-declaring interfaces especially when the inheritance chain becomes large. If you want to emphasize that a class implements an important interface, perhaps one way is to add the information in the summary field in the comment for the class for the tool tip to display.

Comment: I think it is confusing too: To me it implies that class A doesn't implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no point other than perhaps for generics constraints i.e. (probably wrong syntax but you'll get the point - I think (from memory) constraints have some peculiarities regarding inheritance and applying the constraint)

```
public T MethodName(T gen) where T : I
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, and in fact tools like ReSharper will show you that the second implementation of `I` is redundant.